# $ \{ n^{1/n} \}_{ n \in \mathbb{N}} $

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

How can I prove that $ \{ n^{1/n} \}_{ n \in \mathbb{N}} $
is a decreasing sequence after some $n_0 \in \mathbb{N} $;
and also find out such $n_0$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider the behavior of the function $f(x) = x^{1/x}$.

Comment: Use $y=\frac{lnx}{x}$

Answer (score 3):

**New attempt**

$$
\left(\frac{n^{1/n}}{(n+1)^{1/(n+1)}}\right)^{n\cdot(n+1)} = \frac{n^{{n+1}}}{(n+1)^n} = n\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^n = n\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n
$$
whhere the last $\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is closing in on $\frac{1}{3}$ from below (from $n=4$, it is bigger than $0.3$), so from that point on, the whole expression will be bigger than $1$, and all subsequent terms of the sequence will be smaller than their predecessor.

Comment: You put the powers the wrong way ;)

Comment: n+1 turns into n in last expression

Comment: first inequality seems wrong for n=2

Comment: Now it works out. All this just to not have to differentiate.

Comment: Yes, thanks, the point was to evitate the use of derivatives

Comment: As a former national level competiotion participant in high school, I try to avoid using calculus (differentiation and Lagrange multipliers being the most tempting) when the problems should clearly be possible to solve without.

Comment: Still wrong: for `n = 3`, `(1-1/n)^n` is less than `1/3`.

Comment: @did You're right, I assumed it converged from above, which it doesn't, it converges from below.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sqrt[n+1]{n+1} \leq \sqrt[n]{n} \Leftrightarrow (n+1)^n \leq n^{n+1} \Leftrightarrow (1+\frac{1}{n})^n \leq n$$

The LHS is increasing to $e$, thus the inequality holds for sure for $n \geq 3$., and it is easy to see that

$$(1+\frac{1}{2})^2 > 2$$

Thus, $n_0=3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = x^\frac{1}{x}$. Differentiate this function and you will be able to spot a value of $x_0$ after which $f'(x) < 0$. Let $n_0$ be the first integer after this, and then you'll have $f$ decreasing on $[n_0,\infty)$.

Comment: Why not the first integer **before** that?

Comment: Well, you could probably draw a function with $f(1) < f(2)$, but $f$ decreases after some $x_0 \in (1,2)$.

Comment: Sure but if `f(1) > f(2)`, your method yields `2` although the correct answer is `1`.

Comment: Ah, ok. I didn't actually check what the numbers would be, so I went with what I knew was correct regardless. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since Un the term of your series is positive you can consider Un+1/Un.
You have Un+1/Un = exp[(n ln(n+1) - (n+1) ln(n))/(n (n+1))] = exp[(ln(1+1/n) - ln(n))/n(n+1)].

As you know ln(1+1/n) <= 1/n. Hence, Un+1/Un <= exp[(1 - ln (n))/(n(n+1))]. So after n>=3, the expression in the exponential is negative and Un+1/Un is less than 1.

Hope this helps.